# PHP Multiple Input Text and Input File Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following code Multiple text and type File Using an array to upload file and Text.

in this code, if I remove type file this code is working. but after use file is not work

Here is the Form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
  <?php 
  $data_array = array('text','text2','file','file2');
  foreach($data_array as $data_name){ ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="data_name[]" value="<?php echo $data_name; ?>">
  <?php if(strpos($data_name,'text') !== false){ ?>
  <input name="data_value[]" type="text" /> 
  <?php }
  if(strpos($data_name,'file') !== false){ ?>
   <input name="data_value[]" type="file" /> <?php }
  } ?>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Here is The Php Code, I Think More Improvement on `$_FILE` Part

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    if(isset($_FILES['data_name'])){
        foreach(array_combine($_FILES['data_name'],$_POST['data_value']) as $dataname => $datavalue){
            $file_name = $_FILES['data_name']['name']; 
            echo file_name;  
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['data_name'])){
        foreach(array_combine($_POST['data_name'],$_POST['data_value']) as $dataname => $datavalue){
            echo $dataname.' - '.$datavalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is The Error of File..

```
Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number
of elements in pagename.php on line 25

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in pagename.php on line 25
```

I Need Output Like This -

```
 text = value
 text2 = value2
 file = file.jpg 
 file2  = file2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated explicitly in the error message, `$_FILES['data_name']` and `$_POST['data_value'` are not the same size. (And I'm pretty sure the foreach is failing because the array_combine failed).

That is explained by you here: "*if I remove type file this code is working. but after use file is not work*".

If you want to use `array_combine()`, the arrays must be of the same size.
If you add a filter (eg `if(strpos($data_name,'file') !== false)`) the potential exists that the arrays will not match (as this problem indicates).

One approach would be to filter out the "data_name[]" inputs with the same condition as the "data_value[]" inputs.

Or the other way round: add an `else` on the above mentioned `if` that produces `<input name="data_value[]" type="hidden" />`  (notice the type). This will ensure the arrays are the same size. You will have to figure out what to do with these "dummy" inputs in the php code. Perhaps give them a value (like `value="dummy"`) that you can test on.

Comment: Can You Explain Using Code

Answer (score 1):

replace your php-code with this:

```
function get_names_for_entity($name, $arr)
{
  if (!empty($arr)) {
    $ret = array_values(
      array_filter(
        $arr,
        function ($itm) use ($name) {
          return strpos($itm, $name) !== false;
        }
      )
    );
  } else {
    $ret = [];
  }
  return $ret;
}

$names_a = [
  'file' => get_names_for_entity('file', $_POST['data_name']),
  'text' => get_names_for_entity('text', $_POST['data_name'])
];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['data_value'])) {
      foreach ($_POST['data_value'] as $dataname_idx => $datavalue) {
          echo $names_a['text'][$dataname_idx].' - '.$datavalue;
      }
  }

  if (isset($_FILES['data_value'])) {
      foreach ($_FILES['data_value']['name'] as $dataname_idx => $datavalue) {
          $file_name = $_FILES['data_value']['name'][$dataname_idx];
          echo $names_a['file'][$dataname_idx].' - '.$file_name;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: How Can i Found type File Data_NAME

Comment: @sanjayjoon `$_FILES['data_value']['type'][$dataname_idx]`. See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: No Dear You Not UnderStaend I Need  '<input type="hidden" name="data_name[]" value="<?php echo $data_name; ?>">'  Value for File...

Comment: Please Reed Question Again

Comment: if i'm change the sequence value in array like this `$data_array = array('text','file','text2','file2');` . then result not in sequence text data going to file data and file data going to text data.

Comment: Make two arrays for this? Why your request handling and html form are so tricky? What  goal is?

Comment: I Want To Make a Dynamic Form Using Array and MYSQL(PDO)

Comment: But i Need Single Array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189940/discussion-between-sanjay-joon-and-jigius).